# Connect to ActiveMQ Artemis in localhost from containerized Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, activemq-artemis, connection-refused

I am trying to send to ActiveMQ Artemis running in localhost from a Spring Boot app container via AMQP. My yml config is as follows:

```
spring:
 activemq:
    broker-url: amqp://${HOST_NAME:localhost}:5672
```

I am passing HOST_NAME as `host.docker.internal`, but I am getting the following exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:5672] with root cause
```

`host.docker.internal` worked for connecting to MySql running on local host but not working for ActiveMQ Artemis. I am using Docker desktop for Windows, Docker version 20+.

Comment: Can you provide the `broker.xml` for ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: FWIW, it appears your yml is configured for ActiveMQ 5.x, not ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Does the application work if you run it directly on `localhost` (i.e. _not_ inside Docker)?